# Specifying multiple fields - RMongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

What is the proper syntax for specify multiple fields to be returned?

When one field is specified, I do not have any issues returning results in my cursor:

```
#Field specifications
fields <- mongo.bson.from.list(list(text = 1L))
```

I have tried multiple alternatives for specifying more than one field, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax. An example is below:

```
#Field specifications
fields <- mongo.bson.from.list(list(_id = 0L, text = 1L, name = 1L))
```

I tried doing the specification in the find statement as well:

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, "twitter.test", query, 
                     fields = list(_id = 0L, text = 1L, name = 1L), 
                     sort = count_sort, 
                     limit = 1L)
```

This seems to be a simple issue, but I cannot get the results I am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I overlooked some items while browsing for answers. I have found the solution to my question here: 

https://gist.github.com/Btibert3/7751989

Answer (score 0):

Seems all you need is:

```
fields <- mongo.bson.from.list(c(list(_id = 0L), list(text = 1L), list(name = 1L)))
```